# SQL Server Linked Server with Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro?

Tags: ms-access, linked-server, odbc, oledb, visual-foxpro

We were having some issues with our old Microsoft Visual Fox Pro ODBC driver that we shoehorned into Windows 7 and is no longer supported by Microsoft and has not been for quite a long time...

So when our anti-virus software finally stopped it from working, we needed to find another way to make it work.  The Anti-virus company couldn't help us; they said it was a Microsoft problem, but they did recommend a couple of related KBs from Microsoft, which stated that we should use the `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual Fox Pro`.

After making sure that the `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual Fox Pro` was installed, I created a linked server in `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`:

1. Right clicked the following element in the left hand pane, `<SQL Server Instance> -> Server Objects -> Linked Servers` and clicking `New Linked Server ...` from the context menu.
2. Then in the resulting `New Linked Server` dialog:

   1. On the `General` page:

      1. Entered a name in the `Linked server:` textbox
      2. In the `Server type:` radio button, selected `Other data source`
      3. In the `Provider:` drop down selected `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual Fox Pro`
      4. In the `Product name:` textbox entered `VFPOLEDB`
      5. Entered the path to the data in the `Data source:` textbox.
      6. Clicked OK

I was then able to query the data in the Linked Server, and in order to make this accessible to MS Access on the workstations over an ODBC connection (as well as make it more secure) I created `VIEW`s with only the necessary fields for each of the tables in question using the following syntax:

```
USE <name-of-database-to-store-views-in>
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[name-of-view-likely-the-same-name-as-referred-to-in-access] AS 
SELECT *
  FROM [name-of-linked-server]...[name-of-dbf-file-without-extension]
GO
```

Then on the workstations with the MS-Access Database that used to use the VFP ODBC driver, I created a new ODBC connection to the SQL Server containing the Linked Server, so I could access the VIEWs I just created.

Then in the MS-Access database I added the linked tables (`VIEW`s really) from the ODBC connection, they were imported being named as `dbo_<view-name>` and very similar to `<old-linked-table-name>`.  So I renamed the `<old-linked-table-name>` with a `old_` prefix, and renamed the new ones to `<view-name>` removing the `dbo_` prefix.

It now appears that the Microsoft Access database is able to access those tables correctly, via Linked Table, via ODBC, via SQL Server, via `VIEW`, via Linked-Server, via `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual Fox Pro` without the anti-virus getting in the way; however, I'm using test data to do this at the moment and NOT production; production has several other people accessing it, modifying it, etc...so provided that it turns out to be the case that the MS-Access database is just pulling data, and not writing it out, do you think this will work alright in production?  And what if it is writing the data out?  Will I be okay then too?

Comment: Get a couple of people to try it in the non-production environment.  It sounds like it *should* work.

Comment: As someone who worked with FoxBASE/.../MS_Visual_FoxPro for many years and tried to support access to legacy data after Microsoft [effectively] abandoned it, I feel your pain. However, reading your final paragraph describing the path from Access (linked tables) through SQL Server (linked server) to FoxPro_OLEDB (technology orphaned for *years* now) and then asking "Will I be okay...?" is both bewildering and heartbreaking. My advice: Just stop the madness. Do "whatever it takes" to **permanently** get the data out of FoxPro format and move on.

Comment: I can't do that because that's what their system still uses!